Are there convex polytopes with 1-skeleton given by 4-valent Cayley graphs of $S_{n}$ with generators long cycle, and n-1 cycle?
Consider a 4-valent Cayley graph  generated by  long cycle $(1,2,3,...,n)$ and n-1 cycle $(1,2,3,...n-1)$. (See the beautiful image from Wikipedia below for n=4).
Question 1: Are there convex polytopes  such that the graphs will be their 1-skeletons ? At least for some n ?
Context: Permutohedron is beautiful example where convex polytope give rise to Cayley graph as 1-skeleton. ($S_n$ with neighbour transpositions). Another example - truncated cube.
See more on graph - polytope correspondence in Gil Kalai's blog: https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/ziegler%C2%B4s-lecture-on-the-associahedron/
There are many results in that field: Balinski's theorem , Steinitz's theorem, and those described in Kalai's blog.


By construction those searched for polytopes are just the spherical space polyhedra / hyperbolic space tilings described by the CD diagrams $x(n-1)o(n)x$. In fact the long cycles are the $n$-gonal polygons $o(n)x$, the short cycles are the $(n-1)$-gonal polygons $x(n-1)o$, and the remaining faces are the squares $x\ .\ x$. Eg. $x2o3x$ is just the triangular prism (the digons happen to be represented by its lacing edges), $x3o4x$ is the small rhombicuboctahedron, $x4o5x$ is the small rhombitetrapentagonal tiling, etc.
In the infinite cases of the hyperbolic tilings those Cayley graphs imply a finite modwrap thereof each, by identifying all vertices with identical tuples.
--- rk

Thanks a lot for the great answer !   I wonder for the general case S_n - what is known about the polytope - coordinates ? volume ? Erhhard polynom ? Any other information ? Is there easy way to check that graph corresponds to convex polytope ? PS would you also be so kind to look at the related question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/467754/10446
